UGreen NAS operating system recommendation
I just received my Ugreen NAS. It has an Intel CPU. I'm looking for an alternative operating system for it. I've seen thing with FreeNAS and others. Here's what I'm looking for:

Complete hardware support/drivers
Docker support so that I can setup HomeAssistant or other containers
Basic RAID configurations. Initially I would setup 2 hard drives in a RAID 1, then maybe RAID 5 for the remaining 4 drive bays in the future.
Mac Time Machine support for backups
S3-API compatible backup client so I can replace a cloud backup solution with cheap object storage

